# Arquillian, (embedded) Glassfish & JMS: How to test a worker?

Tags: testing, glassfish, jms, jboss-arquillian

I want to test a JMS-worker included in my glassfish-application using arquillian (to have container-services). My Worker looks the following:

```
package queue.worker;

import javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty;
import javax.ejb.MessageDriven;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;

@MessageDriven(mappedName = "java:app/jms/MailQueue", activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue") })
public class MailWorker implements MessageListener {

public MailWorker() {
}

@Override
public void onMessage(javax.jms.Message inMessage) {
}
}
```

This is the test:

```
package queueTest.worker;

import java.io.File;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.Deployment;
import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ShrinkWrap;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.WebArchive;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import queue.worker.MailWorker;

@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class MailWorkerTest {

@Deployment
public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
    WebArchive archive = ShrinkWrap
            .create(WebArchive.class)
            .addClasses(MailWorker.class)
            .addAsWebInfResource(new File("src/test/resources/WEB-INF/glassfish-resources.xml"),
                    "glassfish-resources.xml")
            .addAsWebInfResource(new File("src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/beans.xml"), "beans.xml");
    return archive;
}

@Inject
protected MailWorker mailWorker;

@Test
public void sendRegisterMail() {
    Assert.assertTrue(true);
}
}
```

Executing this test, the Glassfish-JSM-Queue is started[1], but I get the following error:

org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [MailWorker] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject protected queueTest.worker.MailWorkerTest.mailWorker]

When I remove "@MessageDrivern[...]" at Mailworker.class and replace it with "@ApplicationScoped", e.g., everything works fine - so there seems to be not a problem with Arquillian in general, but JMS-related.

How can I test the JMS/Queue-Worker?

[1]
Dez 23, 2012 12:42:08 AM com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.ResourceAdapter start
Information: MQJMSRA_RA1101: GlassFish MQ JMS Resource Adapter starting: broker is EMBEDDED, connection mode is Direct
Dez 23, 2012 12:42:10 AM com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.ResourceAdapter start
Information: MQJMSRA_RA1101: GlassFish MQ JMS Resource Adapter Started:EMBEDDED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MDBs are not eligible for injection in to other classes. You cannot inject them in to your test case.

Answer (score 3):

Testing MDBs is harder than testing usual EJBs and CDI beans as they are executed asynchronously. Even if you were able to inject them into your test, you could just test the onMessage() method by calling it synchronously.

My approach uses the MDB to only catch the message and to extract the underlying presentation (like String or Object). Then pass the extracted message to a separate CDI bean which has a test alternative.

```java
@MessageDriven(mappedName = "jms/queue/example", activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", 
                propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", 
                propertyValue = "jms/queue/example")
})
public class ExampleMDB implements MessageListener {

    @Inject
    private ExampleMessageHandler exampleMessageHandler;

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
            try {
                exampleMessageHandler.doSomething(textMessage.getText());
            } catch (JMSException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("That was unexpected!", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The ExampleMessageHandler defines doSomething(String text).

For the test scope, we need an implementation that captures the arguments passed to doSomething() and makes them accessible to the test class. You can archieve this with the following implementation:

```java
@Alternative
@ApplicationScoped
public class ExampleMessageHandlerTestable implements ExampleMessageHandler {

    private BlockingQueue<String> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();


    public void doSomething(String text) {
        queue.add(text);
    }

    public String poll(int secondsUntilInterrupt) throws InterruptedException {
        return queue.poll(secondsUntilInterrupt, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

}
```

This is a CDI alternative to the real implementation used by the production code. Now just let the Arquillian test use this alternative. Here's the test class:

```java
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class ExampleMDBGoodTest {

    @Resource(mappedName = "ConnectionFactory", name = "ConnectionFactory")
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @Resource(mappedName = "jms/queue/example", name = "jms/queue/example")
    private Queue queue;

    @Inject
    private ExampleMessageHandler exampleMessageHandler;

    @Deployment
    public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
        WebArchive archive = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "exampleMDB.war")
                .addPackages(true, ExampleMDB.class.getPackage())
                .addAsWebInfResource("hornetq-jms.xml", "hornetq-jms.xml")
                .addAsWebInfResource("beans-alternative.xml", "beans.xml");
        System.out.println(archive.toString(true));
        return archive;
    }

    @Test
    public void testOnMessage() throws Exception {
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);

        TextMessage textMessage = session.createTextMessage("Hello world!");
        producer.send(textMessage);
        session.close();
        connection.close();

        // We cast to our configured handler defined in beans.xml
        ExampleMessageHandlerTestable testHandler = 
                (ExampleMessageHandlerTestable) exampleMessageHandler;
        assertThat(testHandler.poll(10), is("Hello world!"));
    }

}
```

Some explanations what's going on here: The test requests a JMS ConnectionFactory and the Queue on which the MDB listens. These create the JMS messages used by the MDB under test. Then we create a test deployment. The hornetq-jms.xml defines an adhoc queue for the test. By including beans-alternative.xml, we ensure that our test alternative is used by the MDB.

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">

    <alternatives>
        <class>com.github.mcs.arquillian.mdb.example.ExampleMessageHandlerTestable</class>
    </alternatives>

</beans>
```

The test case itself should be straight forward. A new JMS message is sent to the queue. Then we wait up to 10 seconds for a new message within our test alternative. By using a blocking queue, we can define a timeout after which the test fails. But the test itself finishes immediately as soon as the MDB calls the alternative bean.

I have uploaded a small [Maven example project](https://github.com/mcs/arquillian-jms-mdb) from where I copied the above code parts. Because I don't know much about Glassfish, it uses JBoss as managed container. Depending on the JBoss version you might use, you need to change the version of jboss-as-arquillian-container-managed.

Hope that helps someone :-)